# Python script in screen window, cx_oracle error

Tags: python, linux, oracle, cx-oracle

I'm on Cent OS with python3, trying to run a script that connects to an Oracle database through "screen".

From the `screen` window, when I run the `python3 [filename].py` command, I get the below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[filename].py", line 6, in <module>
    from login_credentials import *
  File "/home/[user]/[folder]/login_credentials.py", line 7, in <module>
    import cx_Oracle
ImportError: libclntsh.so.12.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

If I run the same command from a regular terminal, outside of screen, it works fine.

Comment: I think maybe ask this on [su] or [sf] is a good idea, because I think this question is about [tag:screen], and not about the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the following command right after entering screen:

*export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1/lib*

Make sure to point to the *lib* subfolder!